# Stable and strong promoter?

Tags: genetics

I need a mammalian promoter that will maintain stable expression through differentiation.

I was originally planning to employ UbC for this specific project, however new information from a different experiment has come to light and now I need a promoter that has both extreme stability and high strength (as you know, UbC is renowned for it's very low expression rates).

Do any of you have suggestions? Perhaps I should look into a hybrid promoter of sorts...

Thank you,

CDB

Comment: I know the CMV promoter is pretty strong, not sure about its stability.

Comment: How about SV40?

Comment: is there any specificity for cell type or do you need a ubiquitous promoter?

Comment: @MattDMo In my experience, the SV40 promoter is at least 10 fold weaker than the CMV and only expresses for 4 - 5 days. I haven't seen how long CMV expresses for.

Comment: @user137 Yes, I have looked into CMV a little, it has low stability in quite a few cell types though.

Comment: @MattDMo I will look into that.

Comment: @RoverEye It must be ubiquitous (might I add that this requirement has been quite a pain?)

Comment: beta-actin promoter?

Comment: While looking into your suggestions I came across two promising candidates. Does anyone have experience with PGK-1 or EF1a? How stable are they and what is their expression rate?

Comment: HSV-TK promoter is also quite good. Never used PGK-1 and EF1a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be quite an amount of resources to help OP.

Addgene has a page on topic with list and description of common promoters usable in variety of organisms: [Plasmids 101: The Promoter Region](http://blog.addgene.org/plasmids-101-the-promoter-region)

[Experimental biophysics](https://books.google.com/books?id=mB_SBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=common%20mammalian%20promoters&source=bl&ots=NcX30vYRuq&sig=xmiRA2d3OVpt9nUr6XOjECox-uA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zgpTVfTSB8ProATphYC4Dg&ved=0CGsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=common%20mammalian%20promoters&f=false) textbook mentions some useful promoters as well, or this [review](http://www.ohsu.edu/nod/documents/week1/genether.promot.pdf).

Surprisingly, there has been some quantitative analysis of promoter strength: [Systematic Comparison of Constitutive Promoters and the Doxycycline-Inducible Promoter](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0010611), as well as effort toward stronger synthetic (version of CMV) [Synthetic design of strong promoters](http://www.pnas.org/content/107/6/2538.full)

My conclusion is that either viral, or CAG (based on chicken actin) promoters might be useful candidates. But one cannot expect ubiquitous and even expression in various tissues/cells types without fine-tuning expression cassette.